# How to determine matrix D in the following formula: D = ADA' - R +I

Tags: covariance-matrix, matrix

I am trying to isolate the matrix D from the following equation:

$$
D = ADA' - R+I
$$

Within this equation D is the covariance matrix. There can be assumed that A and R matrices are 3x3 matrices with diagonal zero. D is a 3x3 matrix with diagonal non-zero and I is the 3x3 identity matrix. Furthermore, matrices D,R and I are symmetric. A and R are matrices with known values. D is a matrix with variables that I want to know.

Does someone know how you can isolate D within this formula and if this is even possible?

Thank you!

Comment: This looks like a  special case of a [Riccati Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_Riccati_equation) closely related to the discrete-time Kalman filtering.

Comment: If $A$ is invertible you can write this as a [Sylvester_equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation). In general this is a linear equation for $D$ so you can solve it by representing $D$ as a vector (with 9 elements in your case) and converting your equation to the form $M_{9\times 9} vec(D) = b$

Comment: @J Delaney. Yes, as often done to find the stationary distribution of a vector AR(1), one can use $\text{vec}(ADA') = (A' \otimes A') \text{vec}(D)$.

Comment: The matrix notation can be cryptic, but everything follows easily once you recognize the map $\mathcal{L}:D\to D - ADA^\prime$ is linear, because then it's immediate that $D$ solves the *inhomogeneous linear* system $\mathcal{L}D = I-R.$ The rest is a matter of choosing any notation you're comfortable with.

Comment: @Yves thank you for the response! I recognise this equality but is there a general formulation of using this to solve the equation including the R + I? I am still a bit stuck on this part.

Comment: The equation writes as a linear equation in the vector $d:= \text{vec}(D)$. So you can find $d$ then $D$. I think that there are conditions to get a postiive definite (p.d.)  matrix. This will be the case if the eigenvalues of $A$ have modulus $<1$ and if $I- R$ is p.d.